# Javascript changing object properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have an object and I am iterating through it's properties in order to change them (I want to replace 'a.1'-kind to 'a[1]'-kind):

```
.fail(function (data) {

var errors = data.responseJSON;
console.log("Object before: ", errors);


console.log("Changed properties:")
for (var property in errors) {
    if (errors.hasOwnProperty(property)) {



            if (property.includes('.')) {
                property = property.replace(/\./, "[");
                property = property.replace(/$/, "]");
                console.log(property);

            }

    }
}

console.log("Object after: ", errors);
```

The properties change during iteration, but object's properties don't change for real:

[image]

How do I changed object's properties not only while iterating through them, but "forever"?:)

Appreciate any help:)

Comment: Please post actual code and not screenshots.

Comment: Please provide real code through the <> button...

Comment: what would it change?)

Comment: You may read about *passing references vs. pass by value, and call by sharing*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may delete and reassign:

```
if (property.includes('.')) {
    errors[property.replace(/\./, "[").replace(/$/, "]")]=errors[property];
    delete errors[property];
}
```

You may ask why does

```
property=property.replace(..);
```

Not work?
Well property is not related to object in any way. Its just a string...

Comment: `property.replace(/\.(.+)$/, "[$1]")` is slightly more succinct.

Comment: @Jonas w, thank you.
but can you explain, why
1) errors[property.replace(/\./, "[").replace(/$/, "]")]=errors[property]; and not:
errors[property] =errors[property.replace(/\./, "[").replace(/$/, "]")];

Comment: @Jonas w, 
and why do we need to:
 delete errors[property]; ?

Comment: @sergej formin you want to copy errors["a[1]"]=errors["a.1"]; and then delete errors["a.1"] ... And *=* means *copy* not *move*

Comment: @Jonas w, thank you:) 
so when we  errors["a[1]"]=errors["a.1"] we actually add a new "property:value" pair to the object, and then we have to delete old one... I didn't know that just by declaring a new "property:value" pair inside "for... in" loop you are adding this pair to the object.... Thanks again!

Comment: @sergej fomin youre welcome ;) *by the way: thats why js is called dynamic..*

Comment: @Jonas w, wisdom great told me you master:)

Comment: @Jonas by the way, can you reccomend any good reading on JS?:)

Comment: @sergej fomin you could start with http://eloquentjavascript.net... However, my knowledge is based mainly on writing / reading answers on SO...

Answer (score 0):

Like the post from [@Jonas w](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-w) above, you can do a delete and reassign the value.

Another example here (does not include your string replacement/regex logic, but shows how you can update/alter the keys:

```js
let logger = document.querySelector('pre');

let obj = {
  foo: 'foo-value',
  bar: 'foo-value',
  baz: 'foo-value',
  qux: 'foo-value'
};

logger.innerHTML = `Original: ${JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)}\n`;

Object.keys(obj).forEach((oldKey) => {
  let newKey = oldKey + '-new';
  let originalVal = obj[oldKey];
  obj[newKey] = originalVal;
  delete obj[oldKey];
});

logger.innerHTML += `Updated: ${JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)}\n`;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach:

```
function replaceProperties(obj) {

    var newObj = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce(function (newObj, prop) {

        var newProp = prop;

        if (prop.includes('.')) {
            newProp = prop.replace(/\./, "[").replace(/$/, "]");
        }

        newObj[newProp] = obj[prop];

        return newObj;

    }, {});

    return newObj;

}

var newObj = replaceProperties(errors);
```